# How can I increase my frame rate?

Tags: league-of-legends, framerate

I have a MacBook Pro with a 2.2 GHz processor 8 GB of ram and an AMD Raedon HD 6750M 1024 MB Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB Graphics card. After playing League for a year, I've always had low frames, around 20-25. However, now League runs constantly at 15-7 frames and I don't know why. The game starts at a good 30 frames, but when minions spawn, it drops to 15. All of my video settings are at their lowest but what confuses me is that when I jump into a custom game with bots, I run at 20-30 frames the whole time.

Comment: there's a new option called "low spec mode" try that. You may also want to try closing as many programs/background processes as you can before playing, especially anti virus's can have a large impact on performance. You may also want to try cleaning the inside of your macbook if you can. But League is being constantly updated and added to, it stands to reason that it requires more and more resources over time. Another thing, maybe make sure that your graphics card is being used for League over the integrated graphics. Finally could try overclocking, if still not enough time for new hardware

Comment: As low as the requirements for LoL are. Your GPU is equivalent to an 8-year old mid tier GPU, your laptop is 6-7 years old and barely meets LoLs requirements. It's possible the wear and tear of the years further reduces performance. You should really consider spending a few hundred dollars on getting a more modern machine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real way to increase the frames except make it the only program running and change the settings to a minimum. A tutorial on how to do this is provided [here](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752684-Low-Frame-Rate-FPS-Troubleshooting).

Hardware can also be improved with better graphics cards and more RAM.

**EDIT**

The possible reasons that this is happening to you may be of patch [6.22](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-622-notes). Many people have been complaining ([here](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/eEOXRQxG-extreme-fps-drop-after-patch-622)) about this, saying that changing the settings does not affect the frame rate drops, with people saying that the cause is due to the alpha client and the fix is as follows:

> After you joined the game and game finished loading and you're on the summoners rift you gotta do this!
>   ALT+TAB from league of legends > Task Manager > End process Leagueclient.exe!

A few people say that this did not help but the majority say's that it works like normal now but you have to re-log after every game which can become tedious
so many suggest that you:

> Yeah, that works but after the game ends you have to relogin again...so just delete the new client...its too early for that.its full of bugs..

A tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/NEfYrkiw-heres-how-to-delete-the-alpha-client). (NOT SUGGESTED (SEE BELOW))

A commaent from [mbomb007](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/115693/mbomb007) was brought to my attention that this is not the suggested thing to do. According to the comment you must (in a simpler fashion thank god :D )   :

> Don't delete the new client. You'll just have to download it again later. Instead, click the option to use the old client on the login screen (in the bottom-right corner)

For reference a list of patch notes for 6.22 ;

can be found [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-622-notes).

As well as this, many people believe that this has to do with windows 10 updates junking up your computer, which may seem unlikely, but its worth taking a look at if need be.

No one mentioned the frame rate fixing when your fighting against bots but they most likely have not tried this.

Patch 7.1 also brings more Frame rate drops to many people ([here](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/q7ByEn5U-patch-71-fps-drop))

The fix for most people was to

> go into a custom game
>   press ALT+Enter
>   go to video settings and change windowed to borderless.
>   Worked for me. had the same issue /:
>   Good Luck!

So this is not likely a hardware problem as I originally suggested more likely caused by the game developers.

Comment: This isn't true, it depends on his client and when he had those issues (eg:Blood Moon)

Comment: @Oak Would you say that this answer should be removed for bad information?

Comment: Not necessarely, but it's not right either. It's neglecting LoL specific issues that cause slowdowns

Comment: @Oak alright I will edit the answer to provide more information.

Comment: Done. I hope this is more what you had in mind.

Comment: Don't delete the new client. You'll just have to download it again later. Instead, click the option to use the old client on the login screen (in the bottom-right corner).

Comment: This is safer yes? I'll update question.

Comment: I have updated the Question. It still includes the tutorial on how to delete the client in case anyone wants to try it **at their own risk**

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a bank card, you could use [LiquidSky](http://liquidsky.tv).

I am not associated with the service, but I tried it, and it really can be a solution.
The service is in Beta, you have to get a key from various websites.
If they are all out of keys, just wait a few weeks.
The new interface with a even more powerful machines will launch in 2 weeks or so.

Other than that, you can just buy a powerful PC, laptop, and get high framerates.
There is no black magic available sadly that could just "boost" your PC/Mac.

Ps.: I had a friend who wanted to play on very low end machine (several times, different machines), and modifying the settings left and right did not do much. If the machine is just too weak, LoL will always run slow. And that game really needs 60 FPS, you cannot really cast spells and such with stutters.

**If you live in the US, you might want to try "Geforce NOW" too, once it comes out.** ( http://www.geforce.com/geforce-now )
Also a cloud gaming service, though it's a bit (a lot) more pricey, and restricted to the US. However, it uses Nvidia architecture, and will be very fast - so they say.

Comment: I'm always extremely skeptical about cloud based services like that.  I feel like you couldn't escape the input lag.

Comment: @JMac: With "OnLive", that was true. It was a service that went bankrupt since then. It had a considerable input lag. Then I tried Gaikai, Sony bought it since. I could not believe how I feel zero input lag even while playing the available Bad Company 2 trial. || LiquidSky is very close to Gaikai, I can play FPS games on it. Not CS:GO of course, that would be silly, but 99% of the games can work just fine, AND the new version promises an even reduced lag. As I said just now, there is no magic to eliminate lag, but it is so minimal, it's just unnoticeable.

Comment: There will be a free tier to the service, and I am sure there will also be a Trial option once the new service launches. The cheapest package is 10$ for 80 hours - which means the lowest available computer speed. We have no idea what that will mean - the current "High" package tear (which now gives you 80 hours) is really fast. 3 cores of Xeon E5-2690 V3, and 8GB of ram. I tried plenty of games, all ran just fine.

NOTE: The current system has a weak(er) GPU, it's roughly similar to the GTX760, so you cannot play BF1 maxed out on it on 60FPS. The new system will have more punch to it.